# Why $q(]-1,1[)=B(q,0,1)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ a topologique space defined by $\Gamma$ a set of semi norm. Prove that if $q:X\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous semi norm, then 
$$\exists p\in\Gamma_f,\exists \alpha>0:q\leq \alpha p,$$

with $\Gamma_f=\{p_1\vee...\vee p_n\mid p_1,...,p_n\in\Gamma\}.$

So, I have by continuity of $q$ that $q^{-1}(]-1,1[)$ is an open of $X$ that contain $0$. I don't understand why $q^{-1}(]-1,1[)=\mathcal B(q,0,1)$ where $\mathcal B(q,0,1):=\{y\in X\mid q(x)<1\}$.

Comment: Since seminorms attain only non-negative real values, $$q^{-1}(]-1,1[) = q^{-1}([0,1[) = q^{-1}(]-\infty,1[) = \{ x\in X : q(x) < 1\} = \mathcal{B}(q,0,1).$$

Comment: nice ! thanks :)

Comment: actually we could have consider directly $]-\infty ,1[$ instead of $]-1,1[$ no ?